# Routing sub-folder controllers in a multiple domain project under Laravel 5

Tags: controller, laravel-5, laravel-routing, subdirectory

The main question is how could I route controllers in subfolders?
I have a multi-domain project, the thing is that i would like to separate each controller and view into Club and Center folders, but i don't know how to configure a route to search for a controller into a folder.

This is the structure:

```
Controllers
|----------Club
|          |---IndexCtrl
|          |---ClientsCtrl
|          |--- ...
| 
|----------Center
           |----IndexCtrl
           |----UsersCtrl
           |----ServicesCtrl
           |---- ...
```

Here's my `routes.php` file with some configurations saw in other answers:

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Routes for site.club
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
*/
Route::group(array(

  'domain' => 'site.club',
  'namespace' => 'Club',//I saw this on other SO answer, I guess it's the folder
  'prefix' => 'club',//Also on the other SO answer

), function() {

    Route::get('/', [
        'as' => 'publicIndex',
        'uses' =>'IndexCtrl@inicio'
    ]);

});

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Routes for site.center
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
*/
Route::group(array(

  'domain' => 'site.center',
  'namespace' => 'Center',
  'prefix' => 'center',

), function() {

    Route::get('/', [
        'as' => 'adminIndex',
        'uses' =>'IndexCtrl@inicio'
    ]);

});
```

Now my guess is: how would I configure the Controller?, the example just said to set the namespace as the path to the folder, in that case my namespace would be something like this:

```
<?php namespace Site\Http\Controllers\Center;
```

Is that right?

Or do I just have to run `composer dump-autoload`?

The result of the above is an error and it says:

`Class Site\Http\Controllers\IndexCtrl does not exist`

Comment: You are probably getting that error because your file is located in `app/http/controllers/` NOT `site/http/controllers`. Laravel follows PSR-4 convensions which except your files path to be the same as the namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Class Site\Http\Controllers\IndexCtrl does not exist` error is most likely because your file is located at `app/http/controllers/foo` while your namespace is  `site\http\controllers\foo`. Laravel follows PSR-4 conventions which excpect your files path to be the same as the namespace.

```
Route::group([
  'domain'    => 'site.club',
  'namespace' => 'Club',
  'prefix'    => 'club',
], function() {

    Route::get('/', [
        'as' => 'publicIndex',
        'uses' =>'IndexCtrl@inicio'
    ]);

});
```

For the above route group, all routes would be expected to have the following namespace:

`namespace App\Http\Controllers\Center;`

So your `IndexCtrl` should be located in the `/app/http/controllers/center/` directory and class would look something like

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Center;`

class IndexCtrl 
{
    public function inicio()
    {

    }
}
```

Because you have added the prefix option all your routes urls should be prefixed with `/club/`. I.E. The `inicio()` method should be accessible from the url:

`http://site.club/club/`

Comment: It tells me this error now:  `[ReflectionException]                                                   
  Class Site\Http\Controllers\Club\Auth\AuthController does not exist`

Comment: That error was because the Auth controllers were called inside the group, how would i handle auth for both groups?

Comment: The best would probably to have a top level auth group, and include just the auth routes for groups within that, seems like that would have the least replication.